# Exe of School project requires admin to run properly

Tags: c++

One of the requirements for this project is that it must be able to launch w/out admin. It is a massive project, so I can't really show you the source and a meaningful and helpful way

I've gone to some people for help, and they suggest that I look throughout my project for any times I write files. However, I can't think of anywhere else I still do this, and yet the exe will only run in admin mode. If you try and run it in non-admin mode, it crashes.

I understand that it's difficult to debug if you can't see project, but the project is hundreds of files. Mainly, I'm looking for advice on the kinds of things that would cause a program to crash in not admin mode but run perfectly fine in admin mode

Comment: `DefaultDirName=C:\Program Files (x86)\DigiPen\NinjaCade` seems to be writing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\` and only admins can do that afaik. Choose another install target or let the user choose one to avoid the "problem". Or just don't use an installer and distribute some "unpack and run" archive if that is possible with your program.

Comment: Normally, you don't want non-administrative users to install/remove programs in a system. Is it acceptable to provide a compressed archive instead and the user simply launches the executable directly instead of installing it? If not, then it's ok to expect an admin-level user to take care of the installation.

Comment: No,I need to produce an executable. Also, plenty of other projects use the same basic template as I've posted and It's fine if the installer requires admin, the generated exe cannot require admin

Comment: So is your question about installer or the application? what crashes the installer or the application? I suppose the application. Why do you show us the installer code?

Comment: I only showed the installer code to give some more information about the problem. The application crashes. But I can't show you the application code when its tens of thousands of lines long across in hundreds of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the many people suggested, the issue was opening a file with read/write privileges. Even though we were only reading from the file, we opened the file as an fstream instead of an ifstream.

I missed it because the problem was hiding in some string utils functions that were written by another team member who is no longer with the team. Pretty much no one was using those string functions or was aware they existed.

Thanks for yours guys' suggestions regardless!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I don't think you can run and install vcredist_x86.exe without admin privileges.

Other than that, in general to not ask for UAC, I think you need to setup the [PrivilegesRequired](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired) properly.

EDIT: To work-around the need to install vcredist you could use static runtime linking. However, that has some disadvantages as well (for example, memory allocation/deallocation must then be always done in the same memory context, i.e. the same dll/executable - which is always the best policy anyway).

Comment: It's fine if the installer requires admin, the generated exe cannot require admin